# Create array multidimensional from looping

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I want to create array multidimensional from looping, but the results i want don't match expectations, here's my code:

```
$dayCount = 5;
for($i=1;$i<=$dayCount;$i++){
   $days[] = array($i<=9?"0".$i:$i => "string");
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [01] => string
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [02] => string
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [03] => string
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [04] => string
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [05] => string
        )
)
```

My Expected Result:

```
Array
(
    [01] => string
    [02] => string
    [03] => string
    [04] => string
    [05] => string
)
```

how to make it happen? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This notation adds an array as an element to an array.

```
$array[] = array(..);
```

The result is a 2-dimensional array. 
To get a one-dimensional array with self-defined strings as key, do that:

```
$dayCount = 5;
for($i=1;$i<=$dayCount;$i++){
  $myKey = sprintf("%02d",$i);
  $days[$myKey] = "string";
}
```

Attention: for keys> 9, php will generate keys of type integer with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, check the [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be5f651c8a44039c616af16164f8649f77302e87)

```
$dayCount = 5;
for($i=1;$i<=$dayCount;$i++){
   $days[str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)] = "string";
}
var_dump($days);
```